# How to set src attribute of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jstree

In this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ak4Ed/134/ I am trying to set the src attribute of an iframe when the user selects a node :

```
        $('#preview').attr('src', 'http://www.google.com')
```

But the iframe is not being loaded. Am I setting the attribute correctly ?

Here is the fiddle code :

HTML:

```
<div id="demo1" style="height:100px;display:inline-block;"">
<ul>
    <li id="node_1_id">
        <a>Root node 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="child_node_1_id">
                <a>Child node 1</a>
            </li>
            <li id="child_node_2_id">
                <a>Child node 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><a>Team A's Projects</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Iteration 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Story A</a></li>
                    <li><a>Story B</a></li>
                    <li><a>Story C</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>Iteration 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Story D</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <iframe id="iframe" src=""></iframe>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#demo1").jstree({
    "plugins": ["ui", "html_data", "themes", "hotkeys"]
    });

    $("#demo1").on("select_node.jstree", function() {
    var node = $(this).find("a.jstree-clicked").parent("li");

    $('#preview').attr('src', 'http://www.google.com')
    alert("selected node: "+node.attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure google sends `x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iframe's ID is `iframe` and not `preview`; try the following:

```
$('#iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.google.com');
```

Or you could change the `id` of the `iframe`:

```
<iframe id="preview" src=""></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The id of the iframe is set to 'iframe' instead of 'preview'
Use

```
$('#iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.google.com')
```